# how does a constructor-arg having value as String passed to the Constructor accepting Integer?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I'm building a Spring Application project, Which is using a Spring DI (constructor injection) to inject the objects.
There is one Student class -

```
public class Student {
       private int id;
```

and having Constructor

```
public Student(int id)
{this.id = id; }
```

I'm injecting the objects using constructor injection like this ---

```
<constructor-arg name="id" value="1"/>
```

Now, here the value (1) is passed as String but the constructor is accepting int .
I'm not able to figure out, how Spring is doing it. Is it just simple Type cast or something else?

Comment: You are looking for the Spring `ConversionService`.

Comment: Yes, I want to know how it work and how the String is internally type-caste to Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does this job , Below is the notes from spring document .

Below is the text from spring documentation :

4.Each property or constructor argument which is a value must be able to be converted from whatever format it was specified in, to the actual type of that property or constructor argument. By default Spring can convert a value supplied in string format to all built-in types, such as int, long, String, boolean, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Spring does this. The note below is from [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s03.html).

> Each property or constructor argument which is a value must be able to be converted from whatever format it was specified in, to the actual type of that property or constructor argument. By default Spring can convert a value supplied in string format to all built-in types, such as int, long, String, boolean, etc.